# Wordpress homepage 301 redirect to localhost

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've just moved a WordPress website from my local machine to the server. All the normal steps were done, such as updating the SQL database and setting it all up. The only problem is the homepage is 301 redirecting to my local URL even though it has the correct URL to go to. The rest of the website is fine including the admin area. So far I've done the following:

1. Checked the SQL database to look for any localhost URL's
2. Defined the wp_home and wp_siteurl in the wp-config file
3. Also defined it in the functions file
4. Disabled caching
5. Flushed the permalinks
6. Disabled plugins
7. Checked for hardcoded URL's in the PHP
8. Deleted the .htaccess file and created a brand new one

Any further ideas please?

Comment: did you update `siteurl` and `home` in the `options` table? also have you tried loading the site in another browser?

Comment: @Sohrab That's annoying, forgot about trying to load it in another browser. It works fine in another browser so I'm going to assume it's browser caching. Simple mistakes, thanks!

Comment: it is okay, it happens to all of us :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem was just browser caching, just needed to load it in a different browser which was cache free